# Bootstrap Columns

Tags: html, css

For some reason my BS columns don't seem to be stacking horizontally in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7trz7wg/#&togetherjs=dqK8Qr67RE), only on top of each other :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Sue Let The Dogs Out</title>
    <script type="text/css" src=""></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
          <h1>
          Sue Let The Dogs Out!
          </h1>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Testimonials</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <h2> Bespoke Pet Services</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <h4>Around the Bristol Area</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="supporter">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Dog Walking</h3>
            <p>We offer one hour dog walks individually or in a group at extremely competitive rates. The walks take place in safe, traffic free, varied environments such as riverside walks, woodlands and parks. We are happy to deal with all dogs, from the
              smallest through to giant breeds.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>House Sitting</h3>

            <p>We offer overnight pet sitting in the client's home. This unique service is ideal for pet owners who, for example, want a few days or weeks' holiday but are reluctant to kennel board. The majority of cats and dogs, particularly dogs, suffer
              anxiety, stress and depression due to unfamilar surroundings, lack of exercise, stimulation and human companionship.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Pet Sitting</h3>
            <p>We are able to arrange to visit your pet during the day to feed and water them - this can be ideal if you are a cat owner needing to be away for a few days but wishing to avoid the disruption of putting your cat in a cattery, for example.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h4>© Rebecca Townsend Design</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h4>Contact Us</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Could you suggest how I would fix this? I'm pretty new to coding so there will be a lot of mistakes within my code. Please feel free to give me some pointers!

Comment: You must show your code in the question

Comment: You aren't actually including Bootstrap in that fiddle as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually include the Bootstrap files in your HTML somehow. You can use this link or download them and insert them into your project locally.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Bootstrap CSS library in order for the Bootstrap classes to do what you expect them too.

You can use a CDN like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```